# SUBSTRING parameter and pass it to new declared parameter SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I would like to SUBSTRING my parameter and pass the value to a newly declared parameter.

My goal is to - substring the `@par_FiscalCalendarYear`, where I will always have the values like `2022 P1` up to `2022 P12`. So `year` then `space` then letter `P` and then month  e.x `12`. In `Declare` statement I want to substring `year` and `month` seperatly, I tried below code but getting an error

`Must declare the scalar variable "@FiscalCalendarYear".`

```
    Alter PROCEDURE [DW].[SP_Fetch_Data] @par_FiscalCalendarYear varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    /* DW.SP_Fetch_Data @par_FiscalCalendarYear = 2022, @par_FiscalCalendarMonth = 11 */
/*
BALANCE ACCOUNTS
*/
    DECLARE @FiscalCalendarYear int = SELECT SUBSTRING(@par_FiscalCalendarYear,1,4) /* 2022 */
        , @FiscalCalendarMonth int = SELECT SUBSTRING (@par_FiscalCalendarYear,7,10) /* 11 */;
    DECLARE @FiscalCalendarPeriod int = @FiscalCalendarYear * 100 + @FiscalCalendarMonth
```

Comment: You have invalid syntax. It's not `DECLARE @Variable <data type> = SELECT <expr>` it's just `= <expr>` (`DECLARE @Variable <data type> = <expr>`). Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it.  Would you mind to modify my code and answer?  thanks for your replay anyway

Comment: `DECLARE @Variable <data type> = SELECT <expr>` isn't valid syntax; there should be no `SELECT`. *Remove* the `SELECT` from statements.